# the coredns pod is always in the CrashLoopBackOff state

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I created a cluster with kubeadm .and all the pods except for Coredns are up and running, he is always in the CrashLoopBackOff stat. Coredns never started properly.

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          81s
coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          81s
etcd-localhost.localdomain                      1/1     Running            0          33s
kube-apiserver-localhost.localdomain            1/1     Running            0          22s
kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain   1/1     Running            0          40s
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-gltqj                     1/1     Running            0          73s
kube-proxy-x2crp                                1/1     Running            0          81s
kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain            1/1     Running            0          15s
```

- Cloud provider or hardware configuration:

```
vm
2 cpu
4G memory
```

- OS (e.g: `cat /etc/os-release`):

```
centos 7.6
```

- Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`):

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
```

1、 use `journalctl -f -u kubelet`

```
-- Logs begin at 一 2019-08-05 14:29:46 CST. --
8月 05 16:43:29 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:29.325790   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
8月 05 16:43:30 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:30.337973   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
8月 05 16:43:31 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:31.826577   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
8月 05 16:43:35 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:35.781871   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a ("coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"
8月 05 16:43:44 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:44.689542   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
8月 05 16:43:48 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:48.690229   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a ("coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"
8月 05 16:43:58 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:43:58.689996   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
8月 05 16:44:00 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:44:00.690532   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a ("coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"
8月 05 16:44:12 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:44:12.689339   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
8月 05 16:44:14 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:44:14.690199   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a ("coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8_kube-system(34dc0078-481a-4d2d-b013-6c65a1ba8d5a)"
8月 05 16:44:25 localhost.localdomain kubelet[23907]: E0805 16:44:25.689499   23907 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940 ("coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=coredns pod=coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq_kube-system(209945cb-f289-450b-9c25-c0cdc3655940)"
```

2、  use `kubectl describe pod coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8 -n kube-system`

```
Name:                 coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 localhost.localdomain/10.0.2.15
Start Time:           Mon, 05 Aug 2019 16:42:01 +0800
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=5c98db65d4
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.244.0.11
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/coredns-5c98db65d4
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://daf187222dfaa4d686dfd587e782369cb18c7de0c4de4850d8dd871b0dbe200c
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.3.1
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:eb516548c180f8a6e0235034ccee2428027896af16a509786da13022fe95fe8c
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    139
      Started:      Mon, 05 Aug 2019 16:44:53 +0800
      Finished:     Mon, 05 Aug 2019 16:44:52 +0800
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8080/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-hzkdx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-hzkdx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-hzkdx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                    From                            Message
  ----     ------            ----                   ----                            -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  5m7s (x3 over 5m27s)   default-scheduler               0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Normal   Scheduled         5m5s                   default-scheduler               Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-5c98db65d4-v5mg8 to localhost.localdomain
  Normal   Pulled            3m42s (x5 over 5m4s)   kubelet, localhost.localdomain  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.3.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           3m42s (x5 over 5m4s)   kubelet, localhost.localdomain  Created container coredns
  Normal   Started           3m41s (x5 over 5m3s)   kubelet, localhost.localdomain  Started container coredns
  Warning  BackOff           3m40s (x10 over 5m1s)  kubelet, localhost.localdomain  Back-off restarting failed container
```

**Environment**:
- Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`):

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T09:18:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

3、use `kubectl logs coredns-5c98db65d4-qx4mq  -n kube-system`

```
empty
```

4、use  `docker version`

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.39 (downgraded from 1.40)
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        74b1e89
 Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:21:07 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Jun 27 17:26:28 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

5、show the CoreDns yaml file

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision":"1"},"creationTimestamp":"2019-08-05T10:53:11Z","generation":1,"labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"},"name":"coredns","namespace":"kube-system","resourceVersion":"930","selfLink":"/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/coredns","uid":"7250d0fc-7827-4910-bf87-f8340cde9f09"},"spec":{"progressDeadlineSeconds":600,"replicas":2,"revisionHistoryLimit":10,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"}},"strategy":{"rollingUpdate":{"maxSurge":"25%","maxUnavailable":1},"type":"RollingUpdate"},"template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["-conf","/etc/coredns/Corefile"],"image":"k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.3.1","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","livenessProbe":{"failureThreshold":5,"httpGet":{"path":"/health","port":8080,"scheme":"HTTP"},"initialDelaySeconds":60,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":5},"name":"coredns","ports":[{"containerPort":53,"name":"dns","protocol":"UDP"},{"containerPort":53,"name":"dns-tcp","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":9153,"name":"metrics","protocol":"TCP"}],"readinessProbe":{"failureThreshold":3,"httpGet":{"path":"/health","port":8080,"scheme":"HTTP"},"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":1},"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"170Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"70Mi"}},"securityContext":{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":true,"capabilities":{"add":["NET_BIND_SERVICE"],"drop":["all"]},"readOnlyRootFilesystem":true},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/etc/coredns","name":"config-volume","readOnly":true}]}],"dnsPolicy":"Default","nodeSelector":{"beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux"},"priorityClassName":"system-cluster-critical","restartPolicy":"Always","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{},"serviceAccount":"coredns","serviceAccountName":"coredns","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,"tolerations":[{"key":"CriticalAddonsOnly","operator":"Exists"},{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"node-role.kubernetes.io/master"}],"volumes":[{"configMap":{"defaultMode":420,"items":[{"key":"Corefile","path":"Corefile"}],"name":"coredns"},"name":"config-volume"}]}}},"status":{"conditions":[{"lastTransitionTime":"2019-08-05T10:53:26Z","lastUpdateTime":"2019-08-05T10:53:26Z","message":"Deployment does not have minimum availability.","reason":"MinimumReplicasUnavailable","status":"False","type":"Available"},{"lastTransitionTime":"2019-08-06T01:45:12Z","lastUpdateTime":"2019-08-06T01:45:12Z","message":"ReplicaSet \"coredns-5c98db65d4\" has timed out progressing.","reason":"ProgressDeadlineExceeded","status":"False","type":"Progressing"}],"observedGeneration":1,"replicas":2,"unavailableReplicas":2,"updatedReplicas":2}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-08-05T10:53:11Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1334"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/coredns
  uid: 7250d0fc-7827-4910-bf87-f8340cde9f09
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -conf
        - /etc/coredns/Corefile
        image: k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.3.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
"/tmp/kubectl-edit-t5zl3.yaml" 135L, 6559C
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 170Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 70Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - all
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/coredns
          name: config-volume
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: Default
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: coredns
      serviceAccountName: coredns
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
      - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
        operator: Exists
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: Corefile
            path: Corefile
          name: coredns
        name: config-volume
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-08-05T10:53:26Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-08-05T10:53:26Z"
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-08-06T01:50:20Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-08-06T01:50:20Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "coredns-7688bbffb9" is progressing.
    reason: ReplicaSetUpdated
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 2
  replicas: 3
  unavailableReplicas: 3
  updatedReplicas: 2
```

6、 look at the https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#pods-in-runcontainererror-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state but did not solve my problem

7、use `kubeadm init --config ./kubeadm.yml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap` init the cluster

**kubeadm.yml:**

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 10.0.2.15

nodeRegistration:
  taints:
  - effect: PreferNoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.15.0
networking:
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
```

Comment: check if your flannel pods are running corectly

Comment: flannel pods are running

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the node is in ready state
`kubectl get nodes -o wide`

Verify your flannel Network (by default it should be 10.244.0.0/16).
It should be set-up during cluster initialization `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`.

Please also refer to:

- [Kubeadm installation and configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#k8s-install-1)
- [Pods in RunContainerError, CrashLoopBackOff or Error state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#pods-in-runcontainererror-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state)

Take a look for this example:

> If you install a version of Docker older than 1.12.1, remove the MountFlags=slave option when booting dockerd with systemd and restart docker

- [coredns pods have CrashLoopBackOff or Error state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state)

If those steps will not help you, please provide more details about cluster initialization and configuration to recreate this issue.

#### update:

I have reproduced this case using below settings.

```
uname -a
Linux g-dvmpku-0 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

kubectl version:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T09:18:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:32:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T09:15:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
kubelet version: Kubernetes v1.15.1

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces:
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-grgcq             1/1     Running   0          5m22s
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-gvk4w             1/1     Running   0          5m22s
kube-system   etcd-g-dvmpku-0                      1/1     Running   0          4m44s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-g-dvmpku-0            1/1     Running   0          4m32s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-g-dvmpku-0   1/1     Running   0          4m36s
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-zhb9v          1/1     Running   0          4m38s
kube-system   kube-proxy-6mdmr                     1/1     Running   0          5m22s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-g-dvmpku-0            1/1     Running   0          4m25s
```

Everything is working as expected.

I am wondering about coredns image:

```
In your case:
     Image ID:      docker://sha256:eb516548c180f8a6e0235034ccee2428027896af16a509786da13022fe95fe8c
While in my case:
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:02382353821b12c21b062c59184e227e001079bb13ebd01f9d3270ba0fcbf1e4
```

If I am wrong please colaborate with more details.

Comment: I tried, but didn't fix the problem. I updated my problem and added some necessary information